# Can't stream .mp4 using HTML5 from AWS S3 in IE even when content-type is set

Tags: html, internet-explorer, amazon-s3, html5-video

I have .mp4 video files stored in an AWS S3 bucket and I am able to stream these from an HTML5 webpage in chrome, firefox, safari (both desktop and mobile). The HTML code is as follows:

```
<video style="margin: 0 auto; width: 70%; display:block;" controls autoplay>
     <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/item1/16x9/main.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

However, I can't get this to work in IE 11/10/9 (the error I get is "Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path"). I know that the video is encoded properly for IE because if I host it on my local web server the video plays just fine in IE.

I have dug through Stack Overflow and the amazon forums and the main thing people seem to run into is not changing the metadata Content-Type from "application/octet-stream" to "video/mp4". Changing this for me doesn't seem to make any difference for IE:

[image]

At first I thought maybe I just didn't set the content-type correctly in S3, but if I hit the S3 URL using fiddler I can see that the correct content-type is actually getting passed down in the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: XsUylpKUMmFPGEQUYyEVdHlicQK3ge2PH6f2lW7quS7ixsBLgEbGww0+qimVGJS4
x-amz-request-id: AC0B4231F897147C
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 15:09:13 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 14:38:11 GMT
ETag: "123430248eca490c3fbf7a3a361c1118"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 35874512
Server: AmazonS3
```

What's even more strange is that fiddler has a webview display option that can present a video preview using an IE window and that DOES play the video just fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this video to play from S3 in IE?

EDIT 1:

This seems strange... if I change the URL pointing at S3 from https to http, then the video DOES play in IE. This is not an acceptable solution for me, but perhaps points to an issue with IE streaming html5 videos over https? (this sees like it should be a fundamental feature, so I'm not sure if this is true for all https videos.)

EDIT 2:

Ok, so IE seems to play any videos over http that I point to just fine. If my website is hosted over http and the video is hosted over https however, it does not want to play it. So, I pushed my code up to a test server that has https enabled and found that I can play videos over https IF that video is hosted in the same domain. Since S3 is clearly in a different domain, this still doesn't play the video in IE. If I upload a test.html file to S3 that has the above video tag in it, then the video plays fine in IE. If I have that same test.html file hosted on my website it does not play.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be seeing mixed content blocking (HTTP and HTTPs from different domains).  Take a look here: http://wiki.sln.suny.edu/display/SLNKB/Enabling+mixed+content+in+Internet+Explorer

Answer (score 0):

I met the exact same problem. Finally, I found that IE tries to access ocsp.digicert.com before downloading the video and if access fails (because the ocsp.digicert.com is not reachable) then the video cannot be played.

The reason IE tries to access ocsp.digicert.com is the OCSP(Online Certificate Status Protocol). Certificate Authorities (CAs) may revoke the SSL Certificates, and browsers will check the website they accessing is still available (not be revoked).

In general, if OCSP check failed (network unreachable) IE will still do its job. But the video embedded on a different site will be unplayable. I think it's a bug.

You can disable OCSP in IE settings.

**Some References:**

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/04/07/understanding-certificate-revocation-checks/
- https://www.digicert.com/util/utility-test-ocsp-and-crl-access-from-a-server.htm
- http://windowsitpro.com/windows/disabling-internet-explorer-feature-checks-server-certificate-revocation